# How to make lapply function updated inside mapply function

Tags: r

My function is complex and would like to make it as simple as I can. So I tried to use `mapply` since I have many list. However, these list are created via `lapply` function. I tried to update one function (which is the needed output from `mapply` function) however, it does  not updated which return me `NULL`. I meant by updated is to get it new values. Here is my code and try.

```
A1 <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 4,
        0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

A1  <- matrix(A1, 5, 5)

A2 <- c(0, 2, 3, 2, 4,
        0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

A2  <- matrix(A2, 5, 5)

A <- list(A1, A2)

s <- length(A)

AA <- lapply(A, function(x) x > 0)

AA2 <- lapply(A, function(x) x %in% c(2, 7))

AA[is.na(AA)] <- FALSE

AA2[is.na(AA2)] <- FALSE

nAA <- lapply(AA, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

nAA2 <- lapply(AA2, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

AFA <- lapply(1:s, function(i) A[[i]][AA[[i]]])
```

The function that I need to update it inside `mapply` is `llA`.

```
llA <- lapply(1:s, function(i) double(nAA[[i]]+nAA2[[i]]))

FA <-  lapply(AFA, function(x) { which(x %in% c(2, 7))})
```

This my `mapply` function which return `NULL`.

```
 mapply(function(x,y,z,f,g)
       if(x > 0){
  for (i in 1:x){
    if(y[z[i]] == 2) {
      f[[g + i]] <- 2 
    }
  }}
  , x=nAA2,AFA,FA,lAA, nAA)
```

So my `lAA` function which need to be updated are outside the `mapply` function. So, when I tried to update it inside `mapply` function I got `NULL. So I think`null`because nothing are updated. So, how can I make`llA`be updated using`mapply`.

Comment: I guess you are not returning anything. If 'f' is the output needed, then specify 'f' before the last closing `}`

Comment: @akrun thank a lot. I did it. but get an error. I did it like this `mapply(function(x,y,z,f,g)
       if(x > 0){
  for (i in 1:x){
    if(y[z[i]] == 2) {
      f[[g + i]] <- 2 
    }
  } llA <- lapply(1:s, function(i) double(nAA[[i]]+nAA2[[i]])) }
  , x=nAA2,AFA,FA,llA,nAA)}`

Comment: I am not getting any error though.  Also,  I didn't find you returning 'f'

Comment: Could you please add you answer so I can understand you correctly.

Comment: This is what I have `mapply(function(x,y,z,f,g)
       if(x > 0){
  for (i in 1:x){
    if(y[z[i]] == 2) {
      f[[g + i]] <- 2 
    }
  }
   f
}
  , x=nAA2,AFA,FA,llA, nAA)`

Comment: @akrun I got this: `Error: unexpected symbol in "mapply(function(x,y,z,f,g) if(x > 0){ for (i in 1:x){ if(y[z[i]] == 2) { f[[g + i]] <- 2 } } f"`

Comment: I think you may have to format the code before running.  I get `mapply(function(x,y,z,f,g)
        if(x > 0){
   for (i in 1:x){
     if(y[z[i]] == 2) {
       f[[g + i]] <- 2 
     }
   }
    f
 }
   , x=nAA2,AFA,FA,llA, nAA)
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2`

Comment: yes it works now. Thank you so much. But I think the result must only include the 2 without zeros. I will double check my full function.

Comment: that would be something in your function

Comment: I am really surprised. When I applied it to different matrix. Just change all `2` in the second matrix to other number (there is no `2` in the second matrix). but I got this error. `Error in if (y[z[i]] == 2) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: I think that error could be due to NA values try `if(y[z[i]]==2 & !is.na(y[z[i]]))`

Comment: it gave me this: `[,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    0    0
 [5,]    0    0
 [6,]    0    0
 [7,]    0    0
 [8,]    0    0
 [9,]    0    0
[10,]    0    0
[11,]    0    0 `  as a matrix. so should be list.